# Build option from other options in Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

I want a Rundeck job to download a file over HTTP on the Rundeck server, copy that file over to other nodes, do work on that file on the nodes, and then delete the file from the Rundeck server.

So far, I've got three jobs:

- Get File: has "url" and "localfile" options
- Delete File: has "localfile" option
- Main Job: has "url" option.

I have Main Job doing these steps:

- Workflow step: Call "Get File" job with -url ${option.url} -localfile /tmp/tempfile.${job.execid}
- Node step: Copy file to node with SourcePath=/tmp/tempfile.${job.execid} and DestinationPath=/tmp/tempfile.${job.execid}
- Node step: Run inline script on node
- Workflow step: Call "Delete File" job with -localfile /tmp/tempfile.${job.execid}

Is there some way I can define a variable or an option for "localfile" for reuse in all my steps rather than having to put '/tmp/tempfile.${job.execid} in three or four places? If I want to redefine where this tempfile is later, it would be much easier to have one place to change it. I have tried defining an option built from other options in "Main Job", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an environment variable for it, but you still need to pass this variable to next job.

[Context Variable Usage](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#context-variables)

Make sure you [Configuring remote machine for SSH](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#passing-environment-variables-through-remote-command)

Comment: I don't quite follow how this helps me. My main job has four uses of the string "/tmp/tempfile.${job.execid}. Two of these are in its own steps, and two of them are in Job options passed to other jobs. What I'm trying to do is something like this:
- Define "TEMPFILE = /tmp/tempfile.${job.execid} in Main job
- IN EVERY OTHER PLACE in Main Job, use only TEMPFILE. 

I cannot figure out how to define a variable in Main job then use that variable in various steps inside the same Main job